# I want all the solutions to this Diophantine Equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

I want all the solutions to this Diophantine equation. p and q are integers.

$$13pq \pm 1 = p^2 + 21 q^2$$

Solutions always come in pairs. $p=2$ and $q=1$ is one solution and so necessarily $p=-2$ and $q=-1$ is also a solution. Note that p and q must either both be positive or both be negative.

$13 \cdot 2\cdot 1 = 26$

$2^2 + 21\times 1 ^2 = 4 + 21 =25$

$26 - 1 = 25$

I want to find four other pairs of solutions to this equation. If no other solutions  are possible, I want a proof of the impossibility of any other solutions.
Can anyone help ?!

Comment: Please consider using MathJax to format your equations. Also, it is recommended to provide context and own efforts in order to get better support, see the [guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: What do you think you’re using, Quora? And what is that +- stuff? Do you want + or -?

Comment: As you said yourself, this is a Pell-type equation, hence an infinite series of solutions should be expected.

Answer (score 0):

1- equation $13pq-1=p^2+21q^2$

We rewrite it as:

$p^2-13pq+21q^2+1=0$

We solve this equation for p:

$\Delta=(13q)^2-4(21q+1)=85q^2-4$

Let $85q^2-4 =k^2$, this is a Pell like equation which may have some solutions, for example for $q=1$ we have:

$p^2-13p+22=0 \rightarrow k=\Delta=81\rightarrow p=11, p=2$

You may find more solutions by searching or using brute force to find $\Delta$ as a perfect square.

2- Equation $13pq+1=p^2+21q^2$

We rewrite it as:

$p^2-13pq+21q^2-1=0$

$\Delta=(13q)^2-4(21q-1)=85q^2+4$

Now you have Pell like equation $85q^2+4=k^2$ to be solved. For example one solution is :

$q=9\rightarrow k=\Delta=83^2$ which gives $p=100$ and $p=17$.

You may find more solutions by solving the Pell like equation.